# Как отсортировать такой массив?

Tags: php

Привет есть массив данных, который содержит объекты. Массив категории. Массив получает все категории без иерархии.

Каждый объект имеет свойство parent.
Всего массив имеет 10 пунктов, у двоих из них свойство parent = 0, потому что это категории верхнего уровня. Остальные 6 разделяются по 3 для каждого Category Parent и свойство parent для них равняется иду родителя.

И есть такая структура

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Как сделать что бы в цикле создавалось ul а в li выводились name для каждого пункта. И если будет еще один родителя верхнего уровня создать еще один ul и туда поместить названия субкатегории

Comment: *Как сделать что бы в цикле создавалось* - так попробуйте что-нибудь сделать, с проблемами вам тут помогут справиться

Comment: Человек с репутацией задает вопрос и просит за него сделать задание, наверняка зарабатывая репутацию он уже понял как устроен сервис, у меня подозрения что либо просто с этой учетки другой зашел, либо он _дурочка включил_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr=array('category0'=>'3', 'category1'=>'3', 'category2'=>'3', 'category3'=>'3', 'category4'=>'3', 'category5'=>'3', 'category6'=>'3');
foreach($arr as $key =>$value)
 {
if($key=='category0')
            {
for ($tr=1; $tr<=$value; $tr++)
                {

echo '<ul>';
foreach($arr as $key1 =>$value1 ){ 
    if($key1=='category1'){
for ($tr1=1; $tr1<=$value1; $tr1++){
echo '<li>'.'кеуе'.'</li>';
}


}


}
echo '</ul>';
    }
    }
    }
```